# PHP Symfony - Inside Filter, check if action is_secure'd?

Tags: php, security, symfony1

How do I check if the action I am calling was secured in security.yml?

*security.yml*

```
myAction:
  is_secure: false
```

*filter.yml*

```
myFilter:
  class: myFilter
```

Now inside *myFilter* i want to check if the action was secured or not.

```
class myFilter extends sfFilter
{
  public function execute($filterChain)
  {
    if ($this->getContext()->is_secure === false) {
      $filterChain->execute();
    }
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
greg@liche :) ~/source/symfony/1.4 > ack "public function isSecure" --type="php"
lib/request/sfWebRequest.class.php
545:  public function isSecure()

lib/action/sfAction.class.php
407:  public function isSecure()

test/unit/helper/AssetHelperTest.php
29:  public function isSecure()

test/unit/helper/UrlHelperTest.php
30:  public function isSecure()
greg@liche :( ~/source/symfony/1.4 > ack "public function getAction\(" --type="php"
lib/controller/sfController.class.php
258:  public function getAction($moduleName, $actionName)
greg@liche :) ~/source/symfony/1.4 > ack "public function getController\(" --type="php"
lib/util/sfContext.class.php
243:   public function getController(
```

)

Which means that `$this->getContext()->getController()->getAction()->isSecure()` should do it.

Comment: I did find out in the meantime: $this->context->getController()->getActionStack()
                    ->getLastEntry()->getActionInstance()
                    ->getSecurityValue('is_secure');

Comment: i was trying to get this value within an app template and the answer @tilman found worked for me too : $sf_context->getController()->getActionStack()->getLastEntry()->getActionInstance() ->getSecurityValue('is_secure');

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to handle this is to set the type of your filter as security:

```
myFilter:
  class: myFilter
  param:
    type: security
```

Your filter will only be executed on secured (is_secure: true) actions.
Take a look at the sfFilterConfigHandler.class.php source code for more information.